# If I have good reason to expect a certain value as the sample mean and I obtain something very different, should I obtain another sample?

Tags: sampling, outliers

In my specific case, I am measuring the mean of a sample for different values of a factor (let's say the possibilities are integers from 1 to 100). I have very good reason to expect the mean of each sample to be roughly proportional to the value of the factor; in any case, related values for the factor should give related values for the outcome. However, a few sample means deviate quite a lot from the expected value (and the neighbouring means), and I suspect that it is simply due to chance.

How I do I deal with the deviating samples?

I cannot just obtain new samples until I get a value which fits better; that would interfere with the underlying distribution (besides simply being dishonest). But maybe I could obtain just one other sample and replace the old one regardless of the outcome?

Or is it possible to obtain a new and *bigger* sample? If so, how much bigger must it be? Can I pool the old and the new sample?

Or maybe I should just present the data that I got the first time around and note that based on predictions, that particular sample is likely a fluke?

Comment: Are you sure you care about the mean? Maybe what you want to quantify is the number of points far from that mean... Or maybe you want to quantify scatter somehow... It doesn't sound like the mean will be helpful to you.

Comment: @Harvey I don't know for a fact that the mean has a certain value, but I have a prediction (e.g. from theory or an earlier study).

Answer (score 2):

You can check the linearity assumption via a nested models test: a linear trend regression via unstructured ANOVA, with a dummy for each individual level of the factor. In R, this would be something like `lm(y ~ x)` vs `lm(y ~ as.factor(x))`; in Stata, `regress y x` vs `regress y i.x`. Then you can use an F-test between these two models to see if linearity assumption is indeed plausible. If you reject it, you need to rethink what's going on. If you don't, you can cautiously proceed to get more data.

Finally, it will always make a good sense to plot the data and check for outliers. I would probably overlay the linear fit and a loess fit, again to visually check for nonlinearities.